# Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift

Out of nothing I got this error **Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context** in my code:

```
    if textView.text != "" && takenImage != nil && userLocation.text != "" {
        checkInternet()
        // Create and save a new job
        let newJob = Job(text: textView.text, jobImage: takenImage!, addedByUser: (userLabel?.text)!(-> ERROR), userImage: UserImage, location: userLocation.text, passMap: takenLocation, userID: userID, postID: key)
        newJob.save()
    }
```

I tried to solve it with answers from other question, but I didn't got it working...

Job Class:

```
var text: String = ""
var location: String = ""
var map: String?
var passMap: String?
var addedByUser: String?
var userImage: UIImage?
var jobImage: UIImage?
var downloadURL: String?
var userDownloadURL: String?
var numberOfLikes = 0
var numberOfDislikes = 0
let ref: DatabaseReference!
var userID: String?
var postID: String?


init(text: String? = nil, jobImage: UIImage? = nil, addedByUser: String? = nil, userImage: UIImage? = nil, location: String? = nil, passMap: String? = nil, userID: String? = nil, postID: String? = nil, data: [String : Any]) {
    self.text = text!
    self.jobImage = jobImage
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.userImage = userImage
    self.location = location!
    self.passMap = passMap
    self.userID = userID
    self.postID = postID
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("jobs").childByAutoId()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above,

1. Use `userLabel?.text` directly without unwrapping anything. `addedByUser` is of type `String?`.
2. You're using `UserImage` type for `userImage` parameter. Use a `UIImage` instance or `nil` instead.
3. You haven't added `data` parameter in your code.

Here is the code,

```
let newJob = Job(text: textView.text, jobImage: takenImage, addedByUser: userLabel?.text, userImage: nil, location: userLocation.text, passMap: takenLocation, userID: userID, postID: key, data: [:])
```

Avoid unnecessarily *force-unwrap* the `optionals`. It might result in *runtime exception*.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong:

`textView.text != ""`
 You are comparing an optional `String` with a non-optional one.

Replace by:

`if let text = textView.text, text != ""`

Then in your constructor, don't unwrap the text!

If you want keep the optional :

`self.text = text ?? "" //will avoid crash`

Or better:

`init(text: String = "")`

Comment: You *can* compare an optional String with a non-optional one for (in)equality.